# Stripe - get subscription for specific email

Tags: stripe-payments

I have customer email. How to check does customer have valid subscription?
I'm using cUrl.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stripe allows [expand responses](https://stripe.com/docs/expand). Fortunately `subscriptions` property of `customer` object is expandable. Thus, you can reduce the number of API requests and lines of intermediate code.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/search \
  -u $API_KEY: \
  --data-urlencode query="email:'test@example.com'" \
  -d "expand[]"="data.subscriptions" \
  -G
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a two-step process:

First, find the ID of the customer by using their email [like this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=curl):

```sh
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
  -u sk_xxx: \
  -d email=foo@bar.com \
  -G
```

Second, use the customer ID to list all their subscriptions [like this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list?lang=curl):

```sh
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions \
  -u sk_xxx: \
  -d customer=cu_xxx \
  -G
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django or Python you can do this in just this simple way.
First install latest version of API SDK in your project and then write this simple code:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    stripe.api_key=settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    test=stripe.Customer.search(query="email:'arslanbhatti.contact@gmail.com'", 
                        expand=["data.subscriptions"],) 
    print(test)
    template_name = 'home.html'
```